# Can I change how Flexbox shrinks?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to replicate the sections on the following page

I'm using flexbox in my version, however my version using flexbox seems to adjust to smaller screen sizes differently. For example the original that I'm trying to copy eats into the margin first as the screen gets smaller before adjusting the size of the text and images. When it does adjust the size of the the text and image it seems to do it a way that's a lot more asthetically pleasing. Once the screen size hits 960px wide I'm going to use media queries to set flexbox to block. However I'd like the text and images to adjust the same was the originally between 1440px and 960px. I've recorded a video to show what I mean - https://youtu.be/1pKq_UW-3Hk

And here's my code...

```css
.section3-h1 {
    font-size: 3.125rem;
    font-family: "Roboto";
}

button {
    width: 176px;
    height: 47px;
    background: #6442ff;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: "Roboto";
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 18px;
    align-items: center;
    border: none;
}

.section2-head {
    margin: 150px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap-reverse;
}

.section2-text {
    max-width: 537px;
    margin-right: 74px;
}

.button {
    margin-top: 60px;
}

.section3-head {
    margin: 150px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;

}

.section3-text {
    max-width: 537px;
    margin-left: 74px;
    font-family: "Roboto";
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <section id="section2">
        <header class="section2-head">
            <div class="section2-text">
                <h1 class="section2-h1"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit ame. 
                </h1>
                <p>Morbi sit amet varius nunc, blandit vulputate mi. Nulla a lobortis magna. Ut bibendum, augue quis lacinia tempus, justo ligula tincidunt ligula, eu bibendum ante libero imperdiet magna. Mauris vel consectetur arcu. Pellentesque risus tortor, lacinia nec dictum a, sagittis quis turpis. Aliquam dolor ante, rhoncus nec congue at, dictum vitae eros. Integer nec viverra leo. Curabitur blandit pretium rhoncus. In ut egestas elit</p>
                <button class="button">READ MORE</button>
            </div>
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/528x396" alt="" class="section2-img">
        </header>
    </section>

     <section id="section3">
        <header class="section3-head">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/528x396" alt="" class="section3-img">
            <div class="section3-text">
                <h1 class="section3-h1"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit ame. 
                </h1>
                <p>Morbi sit amet varius nunc, blandit vulputate mi. Nulla a lobortis magna. Ut bibendum, augue quis lacinia tempus, justo ligula tincidunt ligula, eu bibendum ante libero imperdiet magna. Mauris vel consectetur arcu. Pellentesque risus tortor, lacinia nec dictum a, sagittis quis turpis. Aliquam dolor ante, rhoncus nec congue at, dictum vitae eros. Integer nec viverra leo. Curabitur blandit pretium rhoncus. In ut egestas elit</p>
                <button class="button">READ MORE</button>
            </div>
        </header>
    </section>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Watching the video and seeing what you are trying to replicate, I think you're approaching this all wrong. You have all the `max-width` properties - which to make it function like your example site is completely unnecessary. Nothing is _eating into the margin_, the margin is percentage based and that changes once they get to mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your code completely rewritten, removing all of the `max-widths` and unnecessary CSS. I added the media query for desktop styles as well.

```css
button {
  width: 176px;
  height: 47px;
  background: #6442ff;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: "Roboto";
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 18px;
  align-items: center;
  border: none;
}

section {
  margin: 0 20px;
  max-width: 1170px;
  padding: 50px 0;
}

section header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

section header .text {
  margin: 30px 0 0 0;
}

section header img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

section.reverse header .text {
  order: 2;
}

section.reverse header img {
  order: 1;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  section {
    margin: 40px auto;
  }
  section header {
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
  }
  section header .text {
    flex: 0 0 calc(50% - 30px);
    margin: 0 0 0 30px;
  }
  section header img {
    flex: 0 0 calc(50% - 30px);
    margin: 0 30px 0 0;
  }
  section.reverse header .text {
    margin: 0 30px 0 0;
    order: 1;
  }
  section.reverse header img {
    order: 2;
    margin: 0 0 0 30px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="container">
  <section id="section2" class="reverse">
    <header class="section2-head">
      <div class="section2-text text">
        <h1 class="section2-h1"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit ame.
        </h1>
        <p>Morbi sit amet varius nunc, blandit vulputate mi. Nulla a lobortis magna. Ut bibendum, augue quis lacinia tempus, justo ligula tincidunt ligula, eu bibendum ante libero imperdiet magna. Mauris vel consectetur arcu. Pellentesque risus tortor, lacinia
          nec dictum a, sagittis quis turpis. Aliquam dolor ante, rhoncus nec congue at, dictum vitae eros. Integer nec viverra leo. Curabitur blandit pretium rhoncus. In ut egestas elit</p>
        <button class="button">READ MORE</button>
      </div>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/528x396" alt="" class="section2-img">
    </header>
  </section>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <section id="section3">
    <header class="section3-head">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/528x396" alt="" class="section3-img">
      <div class="section3-text text">
        <h1 class="section3-h1"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit ame.
        </h1>
        <p>Morbi sit amet varius nunc, blandit vulputate mi. Nulla a lobortis magna. Ut bibendum, augue quis lacinia tempus, justo ligula tincidunt ligula, eu bibendum ante libero imperdiet magna. Mauris vel consectetur arcu. Pellentesque risus tortor, lacinia
          nec dictum a, sagittis quis turpis. Aliquam dolor ante, rhoncus nec congue at, dictum vitae eros. Integer nec viverra leo. Curabitur blandit pretium rhoncus. In ut egestas elit</p>
        <button class="button">READ MORE</button>
      </div>
    </header>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by unccessary CSS. The code that you've re written works responsively, but now I've lost all my margins and the images are now a lot bigger. Would this be easier in Bootstrap? This seems a lot of hassle. Everyone I speak to gives completely different code which all produces different results.

Comment: You can certainly update what I gave you to make it closer to what you want. The problem with your code is that you have been asking questions here on SO getting little fixes here and there, and your code is progressively becoming a bit unwieldy - and I think you're getting lost in the weeds for the next steps. Bootstrap would certainly help, but it's unnecessary in your case. What margins are trying to keep?

Comment: I'm trying to keep all the margins. I want it to be visually 100% the same, with everything spaced same as the orginal. I'm not sure where in your code I'm suppose to make the changes.

Comment: The problem is  you are hard coding values for left and right margins. You may want to consider using percentage based margins so your design remains responsive. We also don't necessarily know what _visually 100%_ the same is. At what break point? What should that look like?

Comment: Here's a link to my github. Sorry I only started learning this stuff a week ago - https://github.com/FlashBangKev/Voltcube - I'm trying to replicate the site https://getkev.co.uk as a learning exercise. I replicated it in figma and then used my limited html knowledge to code it out and then used the CSS that figma provided, which is what is on github. From there I found out that figma uses absolute positioning so the CSS was essentially useless for acheiving a responsive site. Started learning some flexbox the otherday and the orginal questions is basically where I am in that process.

Comment: My figma layout can be viewed here - https://www.figma.com/file/SKTfiLLhIEU92js33eqoGb/Untitled?node-id=0%3A1

Comment: The breakpoint on the orginaly site getkev.co.uk is 960px wide. At which point it switches to block - https://youtu.be/1pKq_UW-3Hk

Comment: You can change the breakpoint to whatever you want in the `@media`. I updated my answer to get closer to your figma layout. Basically just needed to update the margins on the `img` and `text` containers, make the `container` divs max-width smaller. On mobile, because your elements are not output in the same order in each section - section 2 the image follows the text, but in section 3 the text follows the image - you need to either change the markup or keep it `flex` but use `column` as the direction and use the `order` property to switch them.

Comment: Ok so that works perfectly but I've got to admit I've got no idea what's going now. Why is flexbox set to column and block before the media query, but then switches to row, shouldn't it be the other way round?. Also wouldn't I create the text and image as two seperate divs and then position them accordingly with flexbox set to row? Then as for the media query, this part has me baffled "flex: 0 0 calc(50% - 30px);" could you explain what's happening here? Thanks!

Comment: I'm going to add a bunch of comments to move this to chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213625/discussion-between-disinfor-and-flashbangkev).

Answer (score 1):

I've observed that you have written so much redundant code in here. I have reframed you code.

please refer the code below. I have changed all classes and structure to reduce stylesheet overhead.

```
* {
  font-family: "Roboto";
}

.button {
  width: 176px;
  height: 47px;
  background: #6442ff;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: "Roboto";
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 18px;
  align-items: center;
  border: none;
  margin-top: 60px;
}

.container {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.flexbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 0;
}
.flexbox * {
  width: 100%;
}
.marr74 {
  margin-right: 74px;
}
.marl74 {
    margin-left: 74px;
}
.flex-image img {
  width: 100%;
}
.heading {
    font-size: 3.125rem;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 764px){
    .flexbox {
        flex-direction: column;
    }
}
```

And here is HTML

```
<section>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="flexbox">
            <div class="flex-content marr74">
              <p class="heading">Lorem ipsum dolor sit ame. </p>
              <p>Morbi sit amet varius nunc, blandit vulputate mi. Nulla a lobortis magna. Ut bibendum, augue quis lacinia tempus, justo ligula tincidunt ligula, eu bibendum ante libero imperdiet magna. Mauris vel consectetur arcu. Pellentesque risus tortor, lacinia nec dictum a, sagittis quis turpis. Aliquam dolor ante, rhoncus nec congue at, dictum vitae eros. Integer nec viverra leo. Curabitur blandit pretium rhoncus. In ut egestas elit</p>
              <a href="#" class="button">READ MORE</a>
            </div>
            <div class="flex-image"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/528x396" alt="" class="section2-img"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="flexbox">
            <div class="flex-image"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/528x396" alt="" class="section2-img"></div>
            <div class="flex-content marl74">
              <p class="heading">Lorem ipsum dolor sit ame. </p>
              <p>Morbi sit amet varius nunc, blandit vulputate mi. Nulla a lobortis magna. Ut bibendum, augue quis lacinia tempus, justo ligula tincidunt ligula, eu bibendum ante libero imperdiet magna. Mauris vel consectetur arcu. Pellentesque risus tortor, lacinia nec dictum a, sagittis quis turpis. Aliquam dolor ante, rhoncus nec congue at, dictum vitae eros. Integer nec viverra leo. Curabitur blandit pretium rhoncus. In ut egestas elit</p>
              <a href="#" class="button">READ MORE</a>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
```

Also note that you should not use more than one h1 on one single page. This affects the SEO of your website. Instead use p or similar element with font-size to achieve large fonts.

Comment: With your code I can't style my button. If I change it to <button> then some of the styling applies but the button takes up the same width as the text - https://imgur.com/EBcMeZW

Comment: Would it be easier to do this in bootstrap? It seems to be overcomplicated to try and replacate this perfectly with flexbox

Comment: Yes...you can go with bootstrap....also  if you are using button the its not possible to redirect to any page on read more text. U need anchor tag for this

Comment: But note that if you will play with the core html css then you will learn more ways to achive above design in much more beutiful and less code